# Multiple small charges harmful?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I often end up charging my phone several times a day for 5-10 minutes each time. Is this more harmful to the (lithium-ion) battery than a single longer charge?

Comment: Battery University advises to avoid deep discharges, http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table  and recommends operating cycles between 30% and 80%. But I haven't seen any data regarding small cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason why someone want to charge a short while is because they have to use it constantly till battery is low, then charge again.

Such usage will allow battery goes into constant current charging frequently. Keep using the phone and it will heat up, then starts charging and continue heating the batt.

The battery lifespan may get even worse if dodgy design is being implement in the phone. Some manufacturer claim how fast you can charge your phone but all this new features will make you replace the batteries often.

Comment: Li-ion batteries don't get hot at any stage of normal charging phase, nor in constant current, nor in constant voltage (saturation) mode.

Comment: It does when designer want to charge 200% faster. These batts will last slightly a year.

Comment: Charging 200% faster doesn't qualify as **normal** charging phase in my books.

Comment: I agree. That's the trend nowadays where faster charging is a feature to lure customer. Another marketing slogan. "Charge battery to 80% full in 35min".